# Classes How I understand them. Correct me if Im wrong please

Tags: python, class

I really hope this is not a question posed by millions of newbies, but my search didn t really give me a satisfying answer.

So my question is fairly simple. Are classes basically a container for functions with its own namespace? What other functions do they have beside providing a separate namespace and holding functions while making them callable as class atributes? Im asking in a python context.

Oh and thanks for the great help most of you have been!

Comment: I really recommend [this fascinating read](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) about the deep-down nature of python types, classes and objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. More importantly than functions, class instances hold data attributes, allowing you to define new data types beyond what is built into the language; and
2. they support [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

For example, here's a moderately useful class. Since Python files (created with `open`) don't remember their own name, let's make a file class that does.

```
class NamedFile(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._f = f
        self.name = name

    def readline(self):
        return self._f.readline()
```

Had Python not had classes, you'd probably be working with dicts instead:

```
def open_file(name):
    return {"name": name, "f": open(name)}
```

Needless to say, calling `myfile["f"].readline()` all the time will cause your fingers to hurt at some point. You could of course introduce a function `readline` in a `NamedFile` module (namespace), but then you'd always have to use that exact function. By contrast, `NamedFile` instances can be used anywhere you need an object with a `readline` method, so it would be a plug-in replacement for `file` in many situation. That's called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), one of the biggest benefits of OO/class-based programming.

(Also, `dict` is a class, so using it violates the assumption that there are no classes :)

Comment: how do you define new data attributes if all you can use to do that are the built in methods? or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Baf: you set them in `__init__`, usually.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by data atributes, arent they just key value pairs?

Comment: @Baf: added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

In most languages, classes are just pieces of code that describe how to produce an object. That's kinda true in Python too:

```
>>> class ObjectCreator(object):
...       pass
... 

>>> my_object = ObjectCreator()
>>> print my_object
<__main__.ObjectCreator object at 0x8974f2c>
```

But classes are more than that in Python. Classes are objects too.

Yes, objects.

As soon as you use the keyword class, Python executes it and creates an OBJECT. The instruction:

```
>>> class ObjectCreator(object):
...       pass
...
```

creates in memory an object with the name `ObjectCreator`.

This object (the class) is itself capable of creating objects (the instances), and this is why it's a class.

But still, it's an object, and therefore:

- you can assign it to a variable
- you can copy it
- you can add attributes to it
- you can pass it as a function parameter

e.g.:

```
>>> print ObjectCreator # you can print a class because it's an object
<class '__main__.ObjectCreator'>
>>> def echo(o):
...       print o
... 
>>> echo(ObjectCreator) # you can pass a class as a parameter
<class '__main__.ObjectCreator'>
>>> print hasattr(ObjectCreator, 'new_attribute')
False
>>> ObjectCreator.new_attribute = 'foo' # you can add attributes to a class
>>> print hasattr(ObjectCreator, 'new_attribute')
True
>>> print ObjectCreator.new_attribute
foo
>>> ObjectCreatorMirror = ObjectCreator # you can assign a class to a variable
>>> print ObjectCreatorMirror.new_attribute
foo
>>> print ObjectCreatorMirror()
<__main__.ObjectCreator object at 0x8997b4c>
```

Comment: What i find dificult to understand is, and this is gonna sound stupid, how is that different from a function you could
    'def somefunc():
         def newfunction(parameters):
     somefunc.newfunction=newfunction(parameters)' this is probably utter bullcrap but if you could call a function2 in a function1 by a dot it would act like a class. right?

Answer (score 4):

Classes (or objects) are used to provide encapsulation of data and operations that can be performed on that data.

They don't provide namespacing in Python per se; module imports provide the same type of stuff and a module can be entirely functional rather than object oriented.

You might gain some benefit from looking at [OOP With Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml), [Dive into Python, Chapter 5. Objects and Object Oriented Programming](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html) or even just the Wikipedia article on [object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 3):

A class is the definition of an object. In this sense, the class provides a namespace of sorts, but that is not the true purpose of a class. The true purpose is to define what the object will 'look like' - what the object is capable of doing (methods) and what it will know (properties).

Note that my answer is intended to provide a sense of understanding on a relatively non-technical level, which is what my initial trouble was with understanding classes. I'm sure there will be many other great answers to this question; I hope this one adds to your overall understanding.